# Check, if String contains only needed characters. If no - input new String from Scanner

Tags: java, regex

User inputs a string in the console.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner
sc.nextLine();
```

This String should contain only symbols `A,B,C,D,F` (it is possible to be something like this: `AAABCCDDD`

- If string contains at least 1 wrong(not `A,B,C,D,F`) character ->
  user should re-type this string
- If string is correct -> the programm
  should stop

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because of "No research efforts."

Comment: See javadoc for String.matches(regex).

Comment: what you need to use is regular expression. for example something like this: [^A][^B][^C][^D][^F] (NOT A or B ... or F)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a do .. while loop:

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String s;
      do {
        System.out.println("Eingabe: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        s =sc.nextLine();
      }while (checkInput(s));
    }

    public static boolean checkInput(String s){
      if (s.matches("[ABCDE]+")){
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
}
```